# Optimized modulo by a constant at runtime

Tags: optimization, modulo, integer-division

Compilers often have various methods for optimizing division and modulo by a constant into other operations. This is described in [hackers delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf) (see also [this page](http://www.hackersdelight.org/magic.htm)).

There is also some discussion regarding hash maps and how slow the modulo instruction is, and how to best map many large numbers into buffers of various sizes. One example is [found here](https://probablydance.com/2018/06/16/fibonacci-hashing-the-optimization-that-the-world-forgot-or-a-better-alternative-to-integer-modulo/).

The question is: can we, at runtime, precompute the needed constants for such an optimized modulo operation, such that it can be used to compute the modulo operation faster than using the modulo instruction?

The linked hackers delight article focuses more on division than remainder, although of course remainder could be computed using rem = n - m*div where n/m = div + rem/m.

One thing that worries me regarding this is that when it's done with the compiler, the constants are actual constants in the instructions, while if done at runtime, they would also be references to memory. I don't know if it's possible to generate executable instructions at runtime to overcome this.

Comment: yes, you can calculate it just like how the compiler calculates during its runtime. However it's only worth the effort if that division is used multiple times

Comment: IMO, there is about nothing to be gained in hard-coding the constants as immediate arguments instead of using an array of constants.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are saving a memory fetch, of which you only got 2 / cycle, and takes 4+ cycles to fetch, 4 if your lucky its in L1$, 300+ if its in main memory.

Comment: It seems that a new rust crate can perform this task: https://crates.io/crates/strength_reduce